# how modify data in R based on information on each column

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a DataSete with more than 500,000 women.

```
    library(tidyverse)
    sample <- tibble( 
    iD=c(1),
    age=c(38), child.age1=c(13),child.age2=c(9), child.age3=c(NA),  asfr15=( 0.0000), asfr16=( 
   7.40444),  
   asfr17=( 42.87749),  asfr18=(73.05321),asfr19=(98.28869),asfr20=( 144.9568),asfr21= 
   (164.976),asfr22=(180.280),asfr23=(191.304),asfr24=(198.4832),asfr25=(202.0248),
   asfr26=(202.1360),asfr27=( 200.3920),asfr28=(197.6840),asfr29=( 193.7632),
   asfr30=(187.6072),asfr31=(179.5616),asfr32=( 170.5096),asfr33=( 160.8376),asfr34=( 
   150.4840),asfr35=( 139.3304),asfr36=( 127.7960),asfr37=( 115.0280),asfr38=( 100.7200),
   asfr39=(85.6256),asfr40=( 182.4384),asfr41=( 178.412),asfr42=( 171.928), asfr43=( 
   163.316),asfr44=( 152.9056),asfr45=( 141.0264),asfr46=( 128.008),asfr47=( 114.180),asfr48=( 
   99.872), asfr49=( 85.4136))
```

I need to subtract age from each child's age and then for each product, -+ 1 of it make asfrs equal to zero on those ages. for instance, for the first child.age
38-13=25
asfr25 +-1 be equal to zero. (,asfr24,asfr25, asfr26)
and in the next step, since the age of the mother is 38, all asfrs above age 38 turn to zero(asfr39-asfr49)

Comment: Please include the desired output for your sample input so that possible solutions can be tested and verified. Maybe drop some of the the columns from the example so it's easier to see what's going on. The same solution that works for 4 columns should work for 20 later. Have you tried anything at all yet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be sufficiently fast.

**Code**

Define a function

```
correct = \(row) {
  age_m = row[names(row) %in% "age"]
  diff = age_m - row[grepl("child.age", names(row))]
  # asfr49 ^= column with highest number
  idx <- unique(c(diff-1L, diff, diff+1L, age_m:49L))
  row[names(row) %in% paste0("asfr", idx)] <- 0L 
  row
}
```

and apply it row-wise:

```
# replace sample2 with your real data 
sample2 <- as.data.frame(t(apply(sample2, 1L, correct)))
```

**Explanation**

The function `correct()` is designed to take a single row as input.
Therefore, we need to apply `correct()` on each row of the data frame. To achieve this, we use `apply()` with `MARGIN = 1L` (specification: operate row-wise). `apply()` does not return a data frame, hence we wrap the transposed result (`t()`) in `as.data.frame()`.
Note. We write `1L` instead of `1` to indicate an integer. `\(x)` is shorthand for `function(x)`.

**Modified data for testing**

```
# set.seed(2711)
n <- 5e5
sample2 <- sample[rep(seq_len(nrow(sample)), n), ]
sample2$child.age1 <- floor(rnorm(n, 13L, 2L))
```

Comment: Dear @Friede, thank you for your response. I really appreciate the information you provided. Your code produces the exact thing that I need but since I am not proficinal code writer, I have problem understand your code, could you please if it is possible, explain the code and what it is doing.

Comment: Tried, please see my update.

Comment: In my data, all women don't have same amount of childern; therefore, in some "child.age" columns, we can see NA. So, the cod does not work well with such cases. I really appreciate it if you provide a strategy dealing with NA.

Comment: Can you please provide rows, where the code does not work well due to NAs? And please explain the issues.

Comment: I have faced with this error in actual data. As far as I understood, there is no difference with actual data and the sample I have provided.  
Error in age_m - row[grepl("born", names(row))] : 
        non-numeric argument to binary operator

Comment: Is this error thrown by applying to `sample`? What is `born`? Do you have character columns in your real data?

Comment: The "born" in actual data is equal to child.age. No, it does seem so; however, I try to exchange data to character, but I still have had a some error.

Comment: I would really like to help, but without you providing rows causing errors I do not know how.