# How can write a function by which we can change our variables based on other variables in a data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, function

I have a dataset that contains information about more than 500,000 women. Below, I bring one of the cases in the dataset.

```
library(tidyverse)
sample <- tibble( 
  iD=c(1),
  Mother.age=c(45),child.age1=c(21),child.age2=c(15),child.age3=c(8),child.age4=c(NA),child.age5=c(NA),
  ASFR15=(0.000000),ASFR16=(7.40444),ASFR17=(42.8774),ASFR18=(73.0532),ASFR19=(98.28869),
  ASFR20=(144.9568),ASFR21=(164.976),ASFR22=(180.280),ASFR23=(191.304),ASFR24=(198.4832),
  ASFR25=(202.0248),ASFR26=(202.136),ASFR27=(200.392),ASFR28=(197.684),ASFR29=(193.7632),
  ASFR30=(187.6072),ASFR31=(179.561),ASFR32=(170.509),ASFR33=(160.837),ASFR34=(150.4840),
  ASFR35=(139.3304),ASFR36=(127.796),ASFR37=(115.028),ASFR38=(100.720),ASFR39=(85.62560),
  ASFR40=(182.4384),ASFR41=(178.412),ASFR42=(171.928),ASFR43=(163.316),ASFR44=(152.9056),
  ASFR45=(141.0264),ASFR46=(128.008),ASFR47=(114.180),ASFR48=(99.8720),ASFR49=(85.41360))
```

My task is to calculate the age difference between each child and their mother. After that, I need to set the ASFR values to zero for every age that matches the age difference. Then, I have to multiply the values before and after the zero cell by 0.25, which means only 25% of the original amount will remain in each cell before and after the zero cell.

To illustrate, suppose the first child is 21, and the mother is 45. In this case, the age difference would be 24. Therefore, the ASFR value for age 24 should be set to zero, while the ASFR values for ages 23 and 25 should be multiplied by 0.25.

Lastly, I need to set all the ASFR values above the mother's age, 45, to zero, including ages 46 to 49.

Answer (score 2):

Base R seems to be sufficiently fast ([related](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77558838/20002111)).

Adapt the wrapper:

```r
calc = \(row, cnms, ASFRmax = 49, perc = 0) {
  m = as.numeric(row["Mother.age"])
  diff = na.omit( m - as.numeric(row[grep("child.age", cnms)]) )
  idx1 = unique(c(diff, m:ASFRmax))
  idx2 = unique(c(diff-1L, diff+1L))
  id1 = cnms %in% paste0("ASFR", idx1)
  id2 = cnms %in% paste0("ASFR", idx2) 
  row[id1] = row[id1] * 0L 
  row[id2] = row[id2] * perc
  return(row)
}
```

Haven't thought about this carefully. Chances are to remove redundancy. Then, `apply` the wrapper row-wisely (`MARGIN = 1L`):

```r
cnms = colnames(sample2)
# sample2 = sample2[!is.na(sample2$Mother.age), ]
sample2 = as.data.frame(t(apply(sample2, 1L, calc, cnms = cnms, perc = .25)))
```

Make sure that `Mother.age` doesn't contain `NA`'s.

---

Your data

```r
sample = tibble::tibble( 
  iD=c(1),
  Mother.age=c(45),child.age1=c(21),child.age2=c(15),child.age3=c(8),child.age4=c(NA),child.age5=c(NA),
  ASFR15=(0.000000),ASFR16=(7.40444),ASFR17=(42.8774),ASFR18=(73.0532),ASFR19=(98.28869),
  ASFR20=(144.9568),ASFR21=(164.976),ASFR22=(180.280),ASFR23=(191.304),ASFR24=(198.4832),
  ASFR25=(202.0248),ASFR26=(202.136),ASFR27=(200.392),ASFR28=(197.684),ASFR29=(193.7632),
  ASFR30=(187.6072),ASFR31=(179.561),ASFR32=(170.509),ASFR33=(160.837),ASFR34=(150.4840),
  ASFR35=(139.3304),ASFR36=(127.796),ASFR37=(115.028),ASFR38=(100.720),ASFR39=(85.62560),
  ASFR40=(182.4384),ASFR41=(178.412),ASFR42=(171.928),ASFR43=(163.316),ASFR44=(152.9056),
  ASFR45=(141.0264),ASFR46=(128.008),ASFR47=(114.180),ASFR48=(99.8720),ASFR49=(85.41360))
```

scaled to 500,000 rows:

```r
set.seed(01252023)
sample2 = sample[rep(seq_len(nrow(sample)), 5e5), ]
sample2$child.age1 = floor(rnorm(5e5, 13, 2)) 
sample2$child.age2 = floor(rnorm(5e5, 20, 3)) 
sample2$child.age3 = floor(rnorm(5e5, 7, .5))
```